# Max File Size & Quantity for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, file, limit

I'm developing an app that will download large files (mostly videos). What I need to know is this:

1. Is there a max singe file size imposed by either Android or iOS? All I've seen is the 4GB limit of a FAT filesystem. The max video size should come no where near that, but we want to be 100% sure that there isn't a lower limit
2. Is there a max amount of space allocated to a single app on either system? Google turned up nothing on this question, so I am going to assume there isn't a limit beyond available file space (which seems logical, but also far to free for an Apple-built system)
3. Is there a max number of individual files or directories for either system? Again, Google turned up nothing. I don't see why there would be here, but I want to cover all the bases here.

Thanks!

Comment: The only limit on iOS is naturally the total available free space of the device. An app can consume as much of this as it likes - but the distributed app file must be under Apple's 2GB limit as per the iTunes Connect Developer Guide. (for reference)

Comment: This is about what I had expected after some time spent on Google. Just wanted to make sure before we went forth with our current plans. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All answers here are for Android:

> Is there a max singe file size imposed by either Android or iOS? All I've seen is the 4GB limit of a FAT filesystem.

I would not exceed 4GB.

> Is there a max amount of space allocated to a single app on either system?

No, there is no per-app quota system at this time. That being said, try not to make users regret using your app. :-)

> Is there a max number of individual files or directories for either system?

Yes, but since the counts should be in the millions, your app will grind to a halt long before you hit those limits.

Comment: "That being said, try not to make users regret using your app." Isn't that the ultimate goal of all devs? Haha. Anyway, this is exactly what I was hoping to see and pretty much re-affirms my suspicions from Google. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

Can't answer for iOS, but for Android, your APK can't exceed 50MB (if it does, you can include expansion files for your additional data).

Here is the link to the docs explaining all the details:
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: Since they are writing "an app that will download large files", limits on the size of the APK are not especially relevant.

Comment: Fair enough, if they don't care about what size app downloaded through the market, the limits won't apply.  I am not sure if there are limits to the size of an app on the file system (I would guess not)?

Comment: Yes, CommonsWare is correct. APK/IPA size limits (both currently set at 50MB OTA, 2GB WiFi, I believe) are not an issue. My APK for the app is currently just over 2MB, the majority of the being UI images that I have not had a chance to convert to hand drawn shapes yet. Unless I do something REALLY wrong, I'll never come close to 50MB